# Good resources for derivations of statistical significance tests

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, references, z-test

I am looking for a good resource to deep dive into mathematical derivations of statistical significance tests such as

- z-test
- one-sided
- two-sided t-test
- pair-wise t-test
- etc.

I can find many resources online on how to perform these test, but I can't find anything that derives why they are true or have the equation they do such as why the z-test has the following equation: $$z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt(N)}$$

Comment: Any of a dozen standard texts on basic mathematical statistics will cover much of this territory, including things like the use of pivotal quantities in tests and CIs. There will also be some sets of notes for university courses available that cover this standard mathematical statistics material. We have some related 'resource' questions, most with the `references` [tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references)

Comment: [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=references*+hypot*+test*+answers%3A1+) gets you there